# Searchkick mapping in test environment not working with the `fields` option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, rspec, searchkick

After an upgrade from Searchkick 1.5.1 to 2.x, the fields option no longer works as a part of a search, but only in the test environment. For example if there is a Lesson with the title "completed":

```
Lesson.reindex
Lesson.searchkick_index.refresh
Lesson.search("Completed", fields: [:title])
```

will return no results in the tests but:

```
Lesson.reindex
Lesson.searchkick_index.refresh
Lesson.search("Completed")
```

will. It appears to have to do with how the index was reindex... not the actual search because if you search the development index from inside the test, it works:

```
Lesson.search("Completed", fields: [:title], index_name: :lessons_development)
```

would return hits, assuming they existed.

I added more detail from the debug output in [this github issue](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/844)

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you index on Rails Console, quit once and restart, then run `Lesson.reindex`. I had the same problem (index is not change by reindex method),